# Upgrade SQLite Database with Transactions

Tags: sqlite, transactions, version, upgrade

I have a website solution that uses on SQLite database for each tenant account.  Without going into much depth about why we chose this solution, we chose it due to SQLite support on distributed/offline systems.

All databases are manipulated using the same PHP file structure.  I wish to update the database version iteratively for all accounts so that they are all at the same version number.

I have a script that loops over each, and can use either PHP(Yii) or the shell to execute queries.

I would like to wrap the manipulation to each database in a transaction.  It appears as though DDL commands may already be auto-commit in nature.

Question:  How to accomplish a SQLite DB upgrade which, if it fails, will report a failure?  Using that report, I could prompt the system to re-attempt or report an error to an admin.  Ideally, I would like to wrap the whole upgrade in a transaction to prevent inconsistencies, but I'm fairly certain that this is not possible.

One thought I had was to backup the database temporarily during upgrade, and delete it on success.

Comment: In SQLite, DDL commands are fully transactional.

Comment: So, it would not be possible to wrap DDL with a "global" transaction.  Thing is, I may require many DDLs and queries to be executed atomically.  Looking more like backing up the database before executing the update may be the best bet, and reverting to the backup before re-attempting the upgrade.

Comment: "Transactional" means that they can be wrapped in a transaction like any other SQL command.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tips.  Will report back with successes, as it looks like each upgrade can indeed be wrapped in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

As CL stated in the comments, DDL is fully transactional in SQLite.  So, for each database in our system, we wrap it in a transaction, and it executes atomically.  We leverage the application to ensure that all databases upgrade successfully if any fail during upgrade.